# Devise rememberable on signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm using devise for the first time in a project so probably this is gonna be a newbie question, I would like to know **how to make a user rememberable after signup**. Currently I'm logging in the user after signup with something like this:

```
class UsersController  <  Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :html, :json, :js

  def create
    if request.format.js? || request.format.json?
      build_resource
      resource.save
      sign_in :user, resource if resource.valid? && request.format.js?
      respond_with resource
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Note I have my own version of create since I need to respond to javascript and json requests. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this yet but you should be able to call `resource.remember_me!` and that should take care of creating the token and saving it for the given resource.

Comment: Hey thanks, it creates and assigns the token to the given resource, but it doesn't set the cookie :P

Comment: Try setting resource.remember_me = true before you call sign_in.  If that doesn't work I'm out of ideas, like I said I haven't actually tried what you're doing before.